# Handlebars -- script in precompiled template doesn't run

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a precompiled handlebars template. I was just having html that I was sending values to (like normal), but I decided I wanted to include a script to be executed when I inserted this into the DOM. However, I haven't been able to get the script to run.

A lot of people seem to have run across this issue when their handlebars template was not precompiled, but I haven't seen many issues where it was precompiled.

Here's the basic structure of my .hbs file:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<script>
    // please do something
    alert('Executing the script');
</script>
```

I'm injecting the handlebars into the DOM and that part is working (the html is injected and the variables are getting set). The script never executes, however.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can create some kind of tag-handler to "inject" script into your handlebars template.

Actually you can't and shouldn't inject scripts like that into Handlebars. It's not HTML.

Comment: @WiktorMociun How do you mean?

Comment: @Skitterm Depends on the browser, what you are trying to archive will not be allowed and will therefore not work. Older browsers are usually more loose about their restrictions with XSS. Most modern browsers don't like script injection via `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comment I wrote while ago, you can't add script directly into Handlebars template.

You can create new HTML tag, which you will dynamically treat like a code that would do the job you want to do. Example:

```
<div data-handlebars-script="example-stack-overflow"></div>
```

or

```
<example-stack-overflow />
```

(I would prefer to go with more standard way - the first one).

And after you render your template you can use e.g. jQuery.

```
$('div[data-handlebars-script="example-stack-overflow"').each(function() { 
  // Do your stuff here
});
```

---

**Edit**

Let me give a comment on side. If you need to do such a thing, that may indicate some kind of flaws in your design.